# How would you define f(7) to make this function continuous?

Tags: calculus, functions, continuity

This is an AP question:

> How would you define $f(7)$ in order to make $f$ continuous at $7$?
>
> $$f(x) = \frac{x^2 - 2x - 3}{x - 7}$$

A long division turns $f$ to

$$f(x) = (x + 5) + \frac{32}{x - 7}.$$

Obviously $f$ tends to infinity at $x = 7$.  I don't see how I could define $f(7)$ to make it continuous.  Is the question problematic?  Any idea?

Comment: Where did you get this question?

Comment: I wonder if there was a typo and what was intended was $$ \frac{x^2-2x-35}{x-7}. $$ $35$ is the only number to which you could change the $3$ to make the question make sense. $\qquad$

Comment: You can't, because it tends to minus infinity. there is a mistake

Comment: Yeah... the question is wrong.  Or it is a meta question to get you to answer "You can't because....".  As Michael Hardy points out though if its a typo of $\frac {x^2-2x-35}{x-7}=\frac {(x-7)(x-5)}{x-7}$ then it's a fair and very neat and clean question.

Comment: @MichaelHardy It is from an AP prep book.  Oh yeah, highly likely so.

Comment: @fleablood The "meta-question" point is interesting, did not think of that.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm assuming it's a typo. (Factoring out the seven just fits too much) But in any event your reasoning is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall: a function $f$ is continuous at $c$ if

$$\lim_{x \to c^+} f(x) = \lim_{x \to c^-} f(x)$$

If one graphs your proposed $f$ (in red below, with $x=7$ in blue), we can see this is not the case: one limit is is $+\infty$ and the other is $-\infty$:

[image]

The likely conclusion is there is a typo; I second Michael Hardy's suggestion from the comments in this matter. Consider instead

$$f(x) = \frac{x^2-2x-35}{x-7}$$

The numerator would factor to $(x-7)(x+5)$, allowing one to conclude that $f(x) = x+5$ for all $x \ne 7$. In light of this, the only sensible definition for $f(7)$, insofar as ensuring continuity goes, would be to ensure that $f(7) = 7+5=12$. This is further verified graphically (though there should be a "hole" at $x=7$ in the red graph), and if desired you can prove the limit through the method of your choice:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can redefine if the discontinuity is removable i.e. if the limit exists at 7. But here the limit does not exist.